# differences in getting properties from muleContext.getRegistry() vs message.getInvocationProperty(...)

Tags: mule, mule-esb

This is for Mule 3.9

My organization is in the process of externalizing all of the properties for our applications.  For apps deployed in cloudhub, the properties will all be set in the Runtime Manager.  For local development, we're using a *context:property-placeholder* to load the properties from a file on the local machine.

One of our projects has a Java Transformer that accesses properties using `muleContext.getRegistry().get(propName)`.  Unfortunately, properties loaded with *context:property-placeholder* do not appear in the registry.  (These properties were previously in *mule-app.properties* which do.)  We're trying to keep the changes associated with externalizing the properties to a minimum. I'm thinking we could set flowVars with the property values and change the transformer to use `message.getInvocationProperty(propName)`.  I'm concerned that there might be ramifications of such a change that I'm not considering.  The developer who wrote the Java transformer is no longer here, so I can't ask why he was getting the values from the registry.

What are the functional differences between using `muleContext.getRegistry().get(propName)` and `message.getInvocationProperty(propName)`?   What are the implications (vis a vis memory, performance, error-handling etc) that need to be considered when switching from one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invocation properties is another name for flow variables (or flowVars). They are completely unrelated to configuration properties. The later come from properties files like mule-app.properties and context:property-placeholder and are set at deployment time. The former are set are execution time inside flows.

I would not recommend trying to access the configuration properties directly from custom Java code. The issue you mentioned is one reason. Also the component gets too tightly coupled on the properties.

Using the flow variables to set the values and read them using `message.getInvocationProperty` which will be more clean from a Java API perspective, though it still couples too tightly the code, now to the variables.

In both cases is not clear for the user of the component that changing the property or flow variable impacts on the transformer, unless they read the Java code.

I think something more clear is to use the Java transformer as a Java bean, and pass the values as Spring properties of the custom component, so the component is not dependent on either. You need to define each value with a setter and use `<spring:property>` on the Mule flow to pass the value, from a configuration property, variable or constant value.

In this way the value being sent to the transformer can be seen from the flow side too.

Example:

Mule config:

```
    <custom-transformer class="com.mycompany.test.CustomTransformer" doc:name="Java">
        <spring:property name="propA" value="${propA}"/>
    </custom-transformer>
```

Java transformer:

```
package com.mycompany.test;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CustomTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    private String propA;

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    

    public CustomTransformer() {}

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage arg0, String arg1)
            throws TransformerException {
        logger.info("propA: {}", propA);
        // TODO Your transformation here
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param propA the propA to set
     */
    public void setPropA(String property1) {
        this.propA = property1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, the spring property approach is definitely better than setting them as flowVars.  So then the question becomes: "Are there differences between the spring property approach and the registry approach that I should be concerned with?" The registry approach seems odd to me, so I'm concerned that it was done that way for a reason that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Maybe there was a reason in the past, but I see no good use for it.